# I am trying to POST a JSON array to a spring-boot controller but nothing happens or even shows up in the logs

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

**ISSUE:**
I am trying to POST to an array to a controller but nothing seems to be happening, there is no info in the logs or on the terminal

I have a JSON array as follows

```
[
    {   
        "artifact_id": 10,
        "session_id":45,
        "user_id": "user99"
    }
]
```

I am trying to use this with a .saveAll() from my CRUD repo but nothing seems to happen it does not even seem to print my System.out.print("test"); message.
My @Entity class is as follows

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "ESearch_results", schema = "public")
public class ESearchResponse {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "primary_key", nullable = false)
    int primary_key;

    @Column(name = "artifact_id")
    int artifact_id;

    @Column(name = "session_id")
    int session_id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    String user_id;
}
```

my controller is as follows

```
@RestController
public class EsearchTestController {
    @Autowired
    private EsearchResponseService EsearchResponseService;
    
    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping("/justATest")
    public String testController(@RequestBody List<ESearchResponse> ESearchResponseTypo){
        String result = "this test passed";

        // System.out.print("\u001B[35m"+EsearchResponseService.saveESearchResult(ESearchResponseTypo));
        System.out.print("\u001B[35m"+ESearchResponseTypo.size());
        EsearchResponseService.saveESearchResult(ESearchResponseTypo);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have tried many things and I believe my root issue here is the way I am passing the JSON array in the request body.

Comment: Have you done some debugging? Could you please post if you get any error? What are the logs? Is it reaching database? Have you tried loading values form database first? And please, could you please stick to Java standard when writing java code? Use camel case for variable names please

Comment: what response code do you get back?

Comment: Have you done some debugging?
I have done some debugging but only wit system out messages and there is no output, my actual debugger does not want to launch for some reason but that is another problem
Could you please post if you get any error?
there are no errors when I try posting to the endpoint infact there are no messages of any sort it even returns back no response but a 200 status 
What are the logs?
the logs contain no meaningful messages just 2 lines indicating the server has started with the endpoint
and yes I can retrieve from the DB and I sorry about the code I am still new

Comment: @rascio I get a 200 OK code but no response, it is supposed to respond "this test passed" but does not

Comment: The only message I get is only when I initially try to POST to the endpoint I get this message
```2022-12-05 13:52:37.845 |  INFO [,0881ade71a92186a,0881ade71a92186a] | Thread Id :  http-nio-8080-exec-1 | Process ID : 31928  | o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-12-05 13:52:37.847 |  INFO [,0881ade71a92186a,0881ade71a92186a] | Thread Id :  http-nio-8080-exec-1 | Process ID : 31928  | o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'```
(cant post the rest because of char limit but its not much)

Answer (score 1):

Try add a `@RequestMapping("/some_path")` to your controller.

I used to getting the same problem, and it was the lack of `@RequestMapping` annotation in my case.

And be careful of your port settings in `properties` file:

```
server.port=8000
```

Comment: I tried this and yet no difference in anything, I can post JSON objects normally but not an array. Am I missing something here? nothing in the logs either.

Comment: Is get request working? Or other data types?

Comment: Yes I can do a GET to pull from the database and I was able to POST a single object of this type easily but when it comes to an array of objects it just doesn't work.

Comment: Do you happen to import the wrong `List` type, it's supposed to be `java.util.List;`

Comment: CORS restriction? Maybe?